# cosine similarity measure c#

Tags: c#, document, cosine-similarity

I have to calculate cosine similarity measure between different documents and queries.

```
private static double[,] getContent()
{
    List<List<string>> documents = new List<List<string>>();

    string query = "access control policies game";
    string document1 = "The game of life. is a game of, everlasting learning";

    char[] separator = new char[] {' ', '.', ',', ':', ';'};
    var splitedQuery = query.Split(separator).ToList();
    var splitedDocument1 = document1.Split(separator).ToList();

    var unicalWords_D1 = (query + " " + document1).Split(separator).GroupBy(g => g).Select(s => s.Key).ToArray();

    documents.Add(splitedQuery);
    documents.Add(splitedDocument1);   

    var array = GetWeights(documents, unicalWords_D1);
    return array; 
}

public static double[,] GetWeights(List<List<string>> splitedDocuments, string[] unicalWords)
{
    double[,] matrix = new double[unicalWords.Count(), splitedDocuments.Count];
    // some processing for term frequency (tf) and inverse term frequency (idf)
    return matrix[j, i] = weight;
}

private static double CalculateCosineSimilarity(double[] vecA, double[] vecB)
{
    var dotProduct = DotProduct(vecA, vecB);
    var magnitudeOfA = Magnitude(vecA);
    var magnitudeOfB = Magnitude(vecB);

    return dotProduct / (magnitudeOfA * magnitudeOfB);
}
private static double DotProduct(double[] vecA, double[] vecB)
{
    double dotProduct = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < vecA.Length; i++)
    {
        dotProduct += (vecA[i] * vecB[i]);
    }
    return dotProduct;
}
private static double Magnitude(double[] vector)
{
    return Math.Sqrt(DotProduct(vector, vector));
}
```

so, all methods are there and here is the main method of class.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var result = getContent();
    var length = result.GetLength(0);
    double[] doc1Array = new double[length];
    double[] doc2Array = new double[length];

    //first doc
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        doc1Array[i] = result[i, 0];
    }

    //second doc
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        doc2Array[i] = result[i, 1];
    }

    var cosSimilarity = CalculateCosineSimilarity(doc1Array, doc2Array);

    Console.WriteLine("Similarity between Query and Doc1: ");
    Console.WriteLine(cosSimilarity);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

It all calculates similarity between query and document1. I have to calculate cosine similarity between different queries and documents, store in an array and sort them descending. How can I get these tasks.

Suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: TBH, This seems a bit lengthy for a SO post; your tasks here seem pretty large. Try to narrow down the scope of the question you need answered. I.e., do you need help with the calculation, some specific method, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do here.  I could use some more explanation on what you mean by "different queries and documents".  How do you want to store them in an array.  Sorting is easy, so you can probably ignore that task.

Comment: I straightly want to take one document and calculate its similarity with number of other queries, sorting the similarity value descending and want to use the top value query